# Meaning of Grützespann, a rare German word

Tags: meaning, literature

I’ve been reading [Wellen](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Keyserling,+Eduard+von/Romane/Wellen/12.+Kapitel), a novel by Eduard Keyserling and I’ve come across the rare word ***Grützespann***. The context is:

> Als die Sonne rot durch die Birkenstämme schien, schlugen sie den Heimweg ein. Sie begegneten Arbeitern vom Felde zurückkehrend, Männer in weißen Leinwandhosen, hinter ihnen her die Frauen mit dem Grützespann in der Hand.

What kind of an object is it?

Answer (score 5):

The only things I found are [here (p. 271)](http://www.lulavi.lv/media/upload/tiny/files/Stendes%20izl%20v%C4%81rdu%20kr%C4%81jums_%202010.pdf) and [here (p. 94/88)](http://digital.staatsbibliothek-berlin.de/werkansicht?PPN=PPN718154363&PHYSID=PHYS_0094&DMDID=DMDLOG_0001&view=fulltext-parallel). According to these documents a "Grützspann" is either some kind of "Suppenschüssel" (**tureen**, bowl) or a larger container (like a **bucket**) for "Saure Grütze" (some sort of red fruit jelly).

I think the different spelling ("Grützspann" vs. "Grützespann") is just artistic freedom. I admit that I never heard the word before (and Google didn't either (almost)), but it would fit.

Comment: Good find! Just a minor correction: "Grütze" was not what we know today as "rote Grütze" (sweet fruit jelly) - But rather any mash made from various grains, sweet or salty, like porridge (groats).

Answer (score 1):

The  [Brockhaus from 1894](http://www.retrobibliothek.de/retrobib/seite.html?id=127961&imageview=true) supplies this information:

> Grütze, grobgemahlenes von den Hülsen befreites Getreide […] Russische
>   oder braune Grütze, die zuerst in einer eisernen Pfanne trocken
>   geröstet und dann im Wasser ausgequollen ist, gibt man in Russland zu der
>   Nationalkohlsuppe.

So, as tofro points out, *Grütze* also means coarsely ground grain, as can be seen by the word *Hafergrütze*. The second part describing a recipe from Russia, where *Grütze* is roasted in an iron pan to be added to cabbage soup, would suggest, that your word is composite of *Grütze* and *Pfanne* (engl. *pan*, also pronounced *Pann* in some German regions). The geographical context seems appropriate, since Keyserling came from *Latvia* bordering to Russia.

Update: Unfortunately the larger context, which I added to the question, is inappropriate for mentioning kitchen equipment.

Comment: And to come full circle: "spañnis" appears to be Latvian for "bucket", at least in the Stende dialect, of which @Perl Dog's first source appears to be a glossary. The plot thickens, along with the Grütze.

Comment: Die Frauen (pl) would rather share the handle of a (one) bucket than  the handle of a  pan, the latter clearly singular in the text.. As a sidemark "spann" in Swedish is an alternative word for "bucket" in southern parts of the country. Seems to be a common germanic word which could have been loaned in to the Latvian

Comment: @Beta Bucket is not convincing either, if nutrition is contained, which is not consumed in amounts justifying a bucket, is perishable and unlikely to have been prepared outdoors to be carried home. I'm no longer sure, that *Grütze* means grinded grain here.

Comment: @guidot, Grütze could refer to animals food, especially for pigs, which would be carried in a bucket.

Comment: I See the Original Q has now been edited and a larger portion of the quotation is shown. In this context, when the workers returns from the fields none of the explanaitions given for "Grütze" could be right, but "Spann" must be Bucket.

Comment: After thinking a while:  this could be a container for the food the workers brought out on the field. The women then of course had to bring the empty buckets home again in teh evening after the day's work.

Comment: @Beta That's exactly what I thought after seeing the longer quotation. And then it could have very well been filled with ground grain. (it's ground, not grinded or am I wrong?)

Comment: @PerlDog: At the evening food would have been eaten mostly, so I see no reason, why a bucket (if it is one) should still be so heavy to require several women to cooperate in carrying. Especially given that [Grimm](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=spann) meaning 3, defines *spann* as a wooden bucket, which has no handle but is carried in the arm. (Thank you for the hint to *ground*.)

Comment: It's not that clear to me that _multiple_ women carry only _one_ Grützspann. I understood that every woman carries her own. Or some do and some don't. Technically "… hinter ihnen her die Frauen mit dem Grützespann in der Hand." means N women and 1 Grützespann. But if I replace Grützespann with e.g. Blumenstrauß, as in "… hinter ihnen her die Frauen mit dem Blumenstrauß in der Hand." then, to my experience, there are N women and M bunches of flowers, although the "_mit je_ einem Blumenstrauß" is omitted.